# v13 <map>#hasAny() Not returning valid results

Tags: discord.js

Im making a permission handler for my bot and I have this following code in a module:

permissionHandler.js

```js
module.exports = {
    async getStaffPermissionFlags(guild, id){
        const adminRoles = ['600912549570936833'];
        const moderatorRoles = ['659905403458682937'];

        const member = await guild.members.cache.get(id);
        if(!member) return;
        return{
            admin: !!member.roles.cache.hasAny(adminRoles),
            moderator: !!member.roles.cache.hasAny(moderatorRoles)
        }
    },
    execute(client){
        client.permissionsHandler = {}
        client.permissionsHandler.getStaffPermissionFlags = this.getStaffPermissionFlags;
    }
}
```

When the bot is started it runs this file and sets the `permissionHandler.getStaffPermissionFlags` object to a function in the module.

I can then later call this by using

```js
await interaction.client.permissionsHandler.getStaffPermissionFlags(interaction.guild, interaction.member.id);
```

The code is intended to return an object with `admin` and `moderator` boolean values but it always returns false for both values even though my test account has both roles with id's `600912549570936833` for admin and `659905403458682937` for moderator.

Am I using it incorrectly or is it a bug within the `@discordjs/collection` package function?

It appears in [the documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=hasAny) that I'm using it right, pass an array to the function.

Comment: Dump the objects to console and read the output.

Comment: Which objects? Also this will be my last reply for the night.

Comment: Try logging `member.roles`. This might explain why it's returning false.

Comment: How do you call this function exactly?

Comment: Perhaps try `await guild.members.fetch(id)` instead of `await guild.members.cache.get(id)`? The member cache can sometimes be outdated, fetching the member instead of getting it from the cache can help ensure the role cache is correct.

Comment: @Cannicide
This cant be the issue. In the function I'm able to log the member id. Even if it diddnt find the member from that it would return the function with no value, it currently returns with a false value.

Comment: @MrMythical Sorry I should have provided more context on the provided code. Its a module method thats called from the client object. I updated the question with current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the issue. It's not listed in the documentation but the arrays passed through the method must be passed in spread syntax. Fixed example is listed below:

```js
const adminRoles = ['600912549570936833'];
const moderatorRoles = ['659905403458682937'];

const member = await guild.members.cache.get(id);
if(!member) return;
return{
    admin: !!member.roles.cache.hasAny(...adminRoles),
    moderator: !!member.roles.cache.hasAny(...moderatorRoles)
}
```